# Centreing a pop up div in the centre of the screen

Tags: css, html, popup

So I've got this:

```
<div class="addedcartbg"><div class="addedcart"> Successfully added to cart. </div></div>
```

And I want it to pop up in the middle of the screen when an image is clicked. The image is currently opening "#" so it just goes to the top of the page.

My problem is, when I set the addedcartbg to position:fixed, it dissapears from the page completely. I also need to know how to centre it in the middle vertically on the screen, I know I can set left and right margins to auto to centre it horizontally, but that doesn't work with top and bottom.

This is my current CSS code for the divs:

```
.addedcartbg .addedcart {
background-color: #999;
height: 40px;
width: 300px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 15px;

}
.addedcartbg {
background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.3);
height: 80px;
width: 320px;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is your lighbox class than modify it like this, this should do the work for you

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPReu/)

```
.addedcartbg {
   background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.3);
   height: 80px;
   width: 320px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-right: 30px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px; /*half of total height + half of top padding*/
   margin-left: -175px; /*half of total width + half of left padding*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just had to change the position to fixed instead of absolute. 

Now how can I make it only visible when a link is clicked?

Comment: @CaiusNewton-Smart I guess that's a jQuery part, and if this helped you than you should mark it as correct so that others can refer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are top and bottom along with position. You might also want to add, style for body.

```
body {
    text-align:center;
/*the rest of your style*/
}

.addedcartbg {
    position: relative;
    top:200;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
/*the rest of your style*/
}
```

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that it'll be viewed on differently sized screens. For example, I work at home on a 1920x1080 res screen, my laptop is 1368x768 and the school computers are 1280x1024, so the top:200; doesn't really work well.

Answer (score 0):

you should also add a z-index

```
.addedcartbg {
  z-index:9999; // include this to avoid overlay of other divs.
}
```